# Show referenced entity

Tags: views, 8

I have 2 content types. For example UserGroup and User. UserGroup has Entity reference field and there are unlimited of Users. I would like to show in views something like this:

- User group name

  - User 1
  - User n
- User group name

  - User 1
  - User n

and for the User their fields (contact, birthday etc.)

Now I set relationships field_users (which is set in UserGroup) and Format -> Show -> Fields. There are Name (UserGroup), Name (User via relationship) but I see:

- UserGroup1

  - User1
- UserGroup1

  - User2

and etc.

Please tell me how can I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: you want UserGroup1 - User1, User2 ... instead of UserGroup1 - User1 UserGroup1 - User2 ? is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I formatted my post.

Comment: Group by User group name in Views format settings

Comment: I tried aggregate:
Aggregation type: Group result together
Group column: value
Group columns: value

but with same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the group level in Views here:
[image]

and then here

[image]